# libGdx достучаться до переменной в Actor

Tags: libgdx

Как мне достучаться до переменных moveX,moveY в актере из вне?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В силу своей неопытности изначально сделал немного неверно.
В конструкторе Enemy() нужно было передавать уже готовые значения,например,setPosition(rx,ry),setWidth(circleWidth) итд.

В итоге я создал еще один класс с нужными переменами,затем в  class Enemy() extends Actor я создал объект.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Замените тело for цикла на:

```
Actor nextActor = stage.getActors().get(i);
nextActor.moveBy(nextActor.moveX, nextActor.moveY);
```

Если переменная в другом модуле, тогда зайдите в build.gradle, затем в `dependencies { }` модуля, которому вы хотите дать доступ к переменной другого модуля. Туда впишите `compile project(':moduleName')`.

Comment: К сожалению,но в том-то и дело,что когда пишу stage.getActors().get(0).? - редактор не выдает,что там есть такая переменная

Comment: @Alexander пробуете достучаться до другого модуля?

Comment: Да,модуль под управлением libGdx ,Я бы дописал туда пару нужных переменных,но файл открывается только для чтения .

Comment: @Alexander чтобы использовать методы/поля другого модуля, надо засунуть этот модуль в dependencies в build.gradle (дополнил в ответе, как это сделать). Но вопрос, libgdx модули же должны быть изолированы друг от друга, а вся общая логика должна быть в core, что обеспечит одинаковое поведение на всех платформах, поэтому зачем вообще необходимо завязывать модули друг на друга? Если это еще один модуль, который вы сами сделали, а не от libgdx, то вопрос снимается)